Using MCMC to fir factory/build data
I have some factory data which reflects natural variability of inputs. For e.g. if I manufacture a bracket for structural support, the Youngs Modulus can be a statistical parameter which varies inherently and so factory data of units manufactured and tested will have some distribution of say the deflection given a certain load applied. Now for the forward model I can run FEA and build a GP or Regression model which predicts the deflection as a function of Youngs Modulus. But once I have the factory data, I want to solve the inverse problem and get a pdf (posterior) of the Young's modulus. I am wondering how to do this, I implemented this using an MHMCMC code which starts with some intitial guess for Youngs modulus and then scans the parameter space. The issue I have is what to use for the MH ratio. Should I just use the likelihood for the deflection based on current value of Young Modulus w.r.t the entire factory data multiplied by priors distribution for the Youngs Modulus? I am yet to see any good examples on how to match factory data using MHMCMC and whenever I run it, I get the prediction for the distributions have very different variance than the factory data. Hopefully this question makes sense.

I may be missing something. Assuming a constant applied load, and assuming nominal dimensions, the relationship between the deflection, and the modulus is totally deterministic (assuming that you stay in the linear portion). So given a deflection, you can directly derive the modulus. Yes, the load is not always constant (but can be measured), nor is the cross section always nominal (but can be measured), so you can account for this variability (or can assume it is minimal?). The rest (material, process variability, etc.) is just the distribution of the modulus?  What am i missing?
